# Decrypt Password encrypted by BlowfishPasswordHasher in cakephp and show it in view file

Tags: cakephp, blowfish

I am using BlowfishPasswordHasher for encrypting password field in cakephp application and it working fine. I need to show the origingal password into view file. Can anyone help me to achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks  in advance.

Comment: _BlowfishPassword**Hasher**_ isn't an _encryption_ mechanism, as the name suggests it's a _hashing_ mechanism, so you won't get the password back - for good reasons that is! You should immediately scratch that idea, decrypting passwords and making them visible is a very, very very bad thing, it's an unnecessary booby trap that just waits to be exploited!

Comment: If you need to show this password temporarily, like in the case of a reset or you need to email the new password to the user then you can make a backup of it *before* encryption and then display the backup. Just make sure that this plain text backup does not get stored into the database or written somewhere in the log files. So maybe rewrite your question to explain why and where do you need to display the password.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing and Encryption are different things in real I think. The real purpose behind hashing is not be able to decrypt. If you want to decrypt your passwords after you save to the database. You should encrypt them using an encryption algorithm such as Mcrypt or Openssl. Actually this is a bad idea if your project is open to public.